# how to successfully populate a combobox in edit template in a gridview? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have a gridview that is set up using an object datasource(web service) to display a table. The table currently comes up, and at the end of the table has an edit option. what i would like to do is when a user clicks the edit option, The row comes up with a dropdown box with available options obtained from a webservice. As of right now the table loads correctly, and comes up with the data from the object datasource. The problem is however, when you click on the edit button, What comes up in the columns that contain a dropbox, and inside of the dropbox, is the pathway for the datasource being linked to the combobox. What is suppose to be there is the Textvalue of that source's object, and when selected the item use's that selected items unique id all obtained from the datasource. Below you will find what i have tried so far:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHolder"
                       runat="server"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                       BorderColor="Black" 
                       BorderStyle="Ridge" 
                       BorderWidth="2px" 
                       DataSourceID="MachineDataSet" 
                       ForeColor="DarkBlue" 
                       HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlign="Center"                             
                       RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
             <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteName"
                                 HeaderText="Site Name" 
                                 SortExpression="SiteName" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name"
                                 HeaderText="Machine Name" 
                                 SortExpression="Name" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Type" 
                                    SortExpression="MachineType">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <telerik:RadComboBox ID="Machine_Type"
                                              runat="server"
                                              EmptyMessage="Select a Machine Type."
                                              EnableLoadOnDemand="true"
                                              DataSourceID="GetMachineType"
                                              EnableVirtualScrolling="true">
                         </telerik:RadComboBox>                             
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MachineType") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Model" SortExpression="MachineModel">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <telerik:RadComboBox ID="Machine_Model"
                                              runat="server"
                                              EmptyMessage="Select a Machine Model."
                                              EnableLoadOnDemand="true"
                                              DataSourceID="GetMachineModel"
                                              EnableVirtualScrolling="true">
                         </telerik:RadComboBox>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MachineModel") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" />
             </Columns>
             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         </asp:GridView>
```

This is the grid i am currently using.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MachineDataSet"
                               runat="server" 
                               SelectMethod="GetMachineSiteDetails"                                   
                               TypeName="Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.FilteredReportInputsSvc.FilteredReportInputsService">
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter DefaultValue=""
                                Name="siteid"
                                Type="String" />
             </SelectParameters>
         </asp:ObjectDataSource>             
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetMachineType" 
                              runat="server" 
                              SelectMethod="GetMachineTypeList" 
                              TypeName="Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.FilteredReportInputsSvc.FilteredReportInputsService">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="siteid" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
         </asp:ObjectDataSource>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetMachineModel" 
                              runat="server" 
                              SelectMethod="GetMachineModelList" 
                              TypeName="Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.FilteredReportInputsSvc.FilteredReportInputsService">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="siteid" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
         </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

These are the object datasources i am currently using.

Now my problem comes up in the edittemplates, And what i believe to be the issue is that the dropbox is in fact getting the correct data, but it has no way to display it properly. 
What i would like to know is how can i get it so that when you click edit, the dropbox will come up in the editable columns of the grid and when they are clicked to display available options it comes up with the selectable items, and not this for each option in the datasource:

> Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.FilteredReportInputsSvc.FilteredReportInputsService

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after mucking around a bit with this i think i figured out the right setup for this using just a regular asp:dropdownlist.

This is now the code i used in my .ascx page:

```
             <asp:GridView ID="GridViewHolder"
                       runat="server"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                       BorderColor="Black" 
                       BorderStyle="Ridge" 
                       BorderWidth="2px" 
                       DataSourceID="MachineDataSet" 
                       ForeColor="DarkBlue" 
                       HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlign="Center"                             
                       RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                       AllowPaging="True">                          
             <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteName"
                                 HeaderText="SiteName" 
                                 SortExpression="SiteName" 
                                 ReadOnly="True" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name"
                                 HeaderText="Machine Name" 
                                 SortExpression="Name" 
                                 ReadOnly="True" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Type" 
                                    SortExpression="MachineType">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetMachineType" 
                                               runat="server" 
                                               SelectMethod="GetMachineTypeList" 
                                               TypeName="Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.FilteredReportInputsSvc.FilteredReportInputsService" 
                                               UpdateMethod="UpdateMachineTypes">
                             <UpdateParameters>
                                 <asp:Parameter Name="machineId" Type="Int32" />
                                 <asp:Parameter Name="machineType" Type="String" />
                             </UpdateParameters>
                             <SelectParameters>
                                 <asp:Parameter Name="siteid" Type="String" />
                             </SelectParameters>
                         </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="Machine_Type" 
                                           runat="server" 
                                           DataSourceID="GetMachineType" 
                                           DataTextField="Name" 
                                           DataValueField="ID" 
                                           Height="17px" 
                                           Width="181px">
                              <asp:ListItem Selected="True" 
                                            Text="Select a Machine Type.">
                              </asp:ListItem>
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MachineType") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Model" SortExpression="MachineModel">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetMachineModel" 
                                               runat="server" 
                                               SelectMethod="GetMachineModelList" 
                                               TypeName="Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.FilteredReportInputsSvc.FilteredReportInputsService" 
                                               UpdateMethod="UpdateMachineModels">
                             <UpdateParameters>
                                 <asp:Parameter Name="machineId" Type="Int32" />
                                 <asp:Parameter Name="machineModel" Type="String" />
                             </UpdateParameters>
                             <SelectParameters>
                                 <asp:Parameter Name="siteid" Type="String" />
                             </SelectParameters>
                         </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="Machine_Model" 
                                           runat="server" 
                                           DataSourceID="GetMachineModel" 
                                           DataTextField="Name" 
                                           DataValueField="ID" 
                                           Width="181px"
                                           Height="17px">
                               <asp:ListItem Selected="True"
                                             Text="Select a Machine Model.">
                               </asp:ListItem>
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MachineModel") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />
             </Columns>
             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         </asp:GridView>
         <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MachineDataSet"
                               runat="server" 
                               SelectMethod="GetMachineSiteDetails"                                   
                               TypeName="Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.FilteredReportInputsSvc.FilteredReportInputsService">
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter DefaultValue=""
                                Name="siteid"
                                Type="String" />
             </SelectParameters>
         </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

If you find anything wrong or have a comment about this design, feel free to comment for i am still pretty new to working with asp.net and any suggestions are a great help!